# Removing NA_character_

Tags: python, r, character, na

I'm reading an excel file in some python code.
I'm using R's readxl function as it is much faster than pandas, then converting it to a python dataframe using rpy2py

Any blank cells are identified as `"NA_character_"` in the python dataframe.

I tried to remove these rows using pythons `dropna(subset=['col'])` with no luck.  The cells still show as `"NA_character_"`

Thank's in advance.

-BigEars

Comment: Something like `i<-is.na(df[['col']])`followed by `df[i, 'col']<-''`. This will substitute zero length character strings for `NA_character_ `

Comment: To drop the entire rows, `df<- na.omit(df)`.

Comment: Rui:  It's python code.  I'm using the readxl function of R because it reads the files faster than the pd.read_excel statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np

dataframe.replace('NA_character_', np.nan, inplace = True)
dataframe.dropna(axis = 'index', inplace = True)
```

Comment: Mateus:  No did not work...no worries...I'll figure out a different approach.

Comment: Hi @Big_Ears. I just used part of your code, but when I saw de documentation, I edited the aswer. Check if it works.

Comment: Mateus:  I think that may do it.  I'll try it, but we did find a workaround.  we brought in the data differently into our Domino environment, which significantly helped.

Comment: Please consider this as 'answered'  I don't see a way of formally marking it as such.